# Is it legal to declare a function that doesn't return anything and doesn't have any arguments?

Tags: c, void

I've seen functions that don't return anything and they are declared as:

```
void foo()
```

I've also seen functions that don't have any arguments as:

```
int foo(void)
```

Is it legal and good practice to declare both at the same time? as in:

```
void foo(void)
```

Comment: If it's compiling and giving output then its legal

Comment: @AlpitAnand: no that's not nearly sufficient for C (or C++).

Comment: is it also good practice?

Comment: @DuarteArribas Being a good practice or not depends on the context.

Comment: The function can just work with global variables (modify them/write them), just print some stuff to screen, so question does not make sense.

Comment: The first example is obsolete, the other two are good, although I don't understand what you mean by "both at the same time." In current practice a function *must* explicitly state its return value, and the arguments it takes (but variations might be tolerated for backward compatibility).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, good practice depends on context. Take following function which does not take any argument and does not return anything as an example:

```
void drawSpecialSeparator(void) {
    int i = 0;
    for (; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%s", (i % 2) ? "--" : "++");
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

can be a simple good example that modularize your code. In addition, It increases your code readability and you can reuse it later easily.

**So, it is good practice to use such functions in correct context.**

*Side note: I personally never use these types of function to change global variable. Maybe it is just my personal taste, but I believe changes in global variables using these function hugely increase code ambiguity.*

Comment: "I personally never use these types of function to change global variable" --- Hmmm note that functions like `strtok(), atoi()`, rand()`, `strto*()`, fputwc` can affect global variables like `errno` and others.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica true(even thogh I di't know about `fputwc`), but I meant that I personally don't write a function which does that. You are forced to use these functions sometimes.

Answer (score 3):

If your function doesn't take any arguments in C, `function_name(void)` is the way to specify that in C.

`function_name()` is obsolete, leads to weaker type checking by the compiler (and is therefore **error prone**), and it can cause your compiler to generate [less optimal calling code](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/_9RwhZ) for the function. (In C++ `void foo();` is exactly the same as `void foo(void);`, but in C they're different.)

In plain C, it's best to simply avoid prototypeless declarations in new code.

`gcc` and `clang` will warn you about them if you compile with `-Wstrict-prototypes`, or you can make them a compilation-aborting error with `-Werror=strict-prototypes`.

Comment: Detail: `function_name();` as a _declaration_ leads to weaker type checking.  In C, `function_name() { ....}` as a _definition_ is like `function_name(void)`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Clang warns about `void foo(){} void call_foo(void){foo(1,2,3);}`  but gcc doesn't (https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/GQzNBA).